# INotifyPropertyChanged Resubscribe not working, only the first time subscription working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I developing a Xamarin application, and I communicating an external custom device. My problem is very strange, firstly the application starting, and connecting automatically to device, so everything is fine. When i suddenly remove the battery from the external device, the bluetooth connection is broken, and it's working fine to, but when I turn on the external device again, my Xamarin application connecting to it very well well, but the subscriptions not working anymore.

I debugged it, but not calling anymore. I think the unsubscribe/subscribe process is wrong.

```
...
if (ble.GetConnectionStatus())
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    ...
                    
                    ble.Adapter.DeviceConnectionLost -= Adapter_DeviceConnectionLost;
                    ble.Adapter.DeviceConnectionLost += Adapter_DeviceConnectionLost;
                    ble.PropertyChanged -= Ble_PropertyChanged;
                    ble.PropertyChanged += Ble_PropertyChanged;
                    data.PropertyChanged -= data_PropertyChanged;
                    data.PropertyChanged += data_PropertyChanged;
                    ...
                });
...
```

So it's so strange, because first time this working, when starting the app, but when I call it after reconnect that same subscription not working. So if its wrong, then why working this at very first time?

I have no error, just not fire the functions again after resubscribe.

So as you see, I need to "refresh" the subscription. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: `ble.PropertyChanged -= Ble_PropertyChanged;
                    ble.PropertyChanged += Ble_PropertyChanged;` doesn't do much. If you reconnect, do you get a new instance?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I create the ble, and the data instance in this page constructor, so its not a new instance

Comment: So the event should be intact.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen do you have any advice what am I wrong?

Comment: *"So if its wrong, then why working this at very first time?"* Its hard to say from the information you've provided. As a test, make a button that when pressed, starts all over from the beginning: creates `ble` and `data` again. Then connects again. Does that work in this situation? If so, that tells you that those instances do not (and maybe cannot) recognize a device that is connected **after** the instances are created.

Answer (score 0):

If that "button to recreate everything" works, then I see two alternatives.

---

Option 1:

- Have such a button, so that user can manually "fix" the situation.

PRO: Gives the user a solution that is guaranteed to work.
CON: Requires user intervention.

Option 2:

- Have a periodic timer, that decides whether/when to forcibly "fix" the situation.

PRO: Automatically recovers.
CON: Risks losing data, if forces a recovery at the same time data is arriving.

---

In pseudo-code, option 2 might be something like this:

```
// pseudo-code
static Timer timer = ..start a timer that has an event every 10 seconds.

OnTimerElapsed:
    if (!eventSeenRecently)
        ForceReset();
    eventSeenRecently = false;

..whereever you receive data..
    if (..has data..)
        eventSeenRecently = true;
```

The concept is that you keep track of whether data continues to be received. If the device stops sending you information (but you believe it should be), then you "ForceReset" - whatever is needed to get everything going again.

---

---

**`DeviceConnectionLost`** should also set some flag, that you use to ForceReset when the device "comes back".

```
// pseudo-code
DeviceConnectionLost:
    resetNeeded = true;

OnTimerElapsed:
    if (resetNeeded && ..test that device is available again..) {
        ForceReset();
        resetNeeded = false;
    }
```

---

Perhaps this custom device has some option or info that can help.

For example, there might be a way to query some id or other info, so you can discover that the device is now "different", in a way that requires the reset. Then the timer does that query, and uses that info to decide to reset.